# Passing a value to Javascript - via a link

Tags: javascript, php

The below excluding the creation of the `$order_id_inpro` is all inside an PHP echo.

```
$order_id_inpro = "1234";
<a class="dropdown-item" onclick="myFunction2('.$order_id_inpro.')">Upgrade Order</a>
```

At the bottom before my `</body>` I have the below script.

```
<script>
function myFunction2() {
  var msg2=encodeURIComponent(this.id);
  var myWindow = window.open("https://myurl.com/OaJER1?orderNumber="+ msg2 , "MsgWindow", "width=650,height=1000");
}
</script>
```

The results is that I get "orderNumber=undefined" at the end of the URL.

Comment: `this` inside your function refers to the `window` object. You are already passing a value in the place where you call the function - so why is your function not _using_ that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onclick` is passing the order number as a function argument, you need to get it using a function parameter.

```js
function myFunction2(msg2) {
  var myWindow = window.open("https://myurl.com/OaJER1?orderNumber=" + msg2, "MsgWindow", "width=650,height=1000");
}
```

Inside the function, `this` is the global `window` object, so `this.id` is `window.id`, which is undefined.

Comment: sorry not sure I follow... so this element is ok?  <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="myFunction2('.$order_id_inpro.')">Upgrade Order</a>

Comment: I assume that's inside a PHP `echo` statement so that the variable concatenation works.

Comment: Hey Barmar, yep see as per the above.      <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="myFunction2('.$order_id_inpro.')">Upgrade Order</a>

Comment: Also if it helps the PHP Echo is line 625 of my page. The javascript if down on line 1337 so later in the page

Comment: What am I supposed to see above? There's no `echo` in the PHP.

Comment: The position on the page makes no difference. The JS doesn't use the PHP variable.

Comment: sorry!  this is my script with the echo echo '<td></td>
 <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle active text-center text-light" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="dropdown_options" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Options</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="dropdown_options">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://url.com/OaJER1?orderNumber='.$order_id_inpro.'" target="_blank">Cancel Order</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="myFunction2('.$order_id_inpro.')">Upgrade Order</a>';

Comment: That's what I assumed it was. So what's the problem?

Comment: I've made the below change to the script and just does not open anything now <script>

function myFunction2(msg2) {

  var myWindow = window.open("https://url.com/OaJER1?orderNumber="+ msg2, "MsgWindow", "width=650,height=1000");
    
}
</script>

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: just checked and got - Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: My code doesn't have a syntax error, so it must be some other code of your own.

Comment: Just double checked the console. This is the line - <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="myFunction2(206588S)">Upgrade Order</a> - And it brings up the following error. Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (at dashboard_development.php?session_id=271290837850111579706931626950414417:372:81)

Comment: That code needs to be in the `<body>` of the HTML, not in a `<script>`

Comment: Yea I got it in the main body. Do I need to add anything else into the function2() call in the onclick?

Comment: No. The function is exactly what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: Yep - see below which i took from your answer - <script>
function myFunction2(msg2) {
var myWindow = window.open("https://myurl.com/OaJER1?orderNumber=" + msg2, "MsgWindow", "width=650,height=1000");
}
</script>
</body>